# KendoUI Grid visibility setting on command

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI Grid that holds records. One of the values in a record is a boolean that I am using to show/hide a command (delete). I was trying to follow the instructions here: 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.command.visible 
I then realized, if you click on the "Preview" it doesn't even work for them. I know I can use a template to set the class of the div tag and then hide it with some jQuery, but would rather do it with their built in feature...if it even work. Has anyone had any luck with the command visible command?

Comment: Is it possible that this config option is new, as is just added with 2017 R1? And the docs aren't using the new javascript files yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is working as expected now. I am also pasting a Dojo just in case:

[Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ifuQU)

Comment: I think that confirms my suspicion that it is a new feature as the 2017.1.117 js/css from the CDN were 404 errors earlier and it clearly did not work with the earlier versions.

Comment: It is indeed a new feature. Also, the links to the CDN had to be fixed to ...2017.1.118... to point to the latest version from today's release.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense...although I wish this was a function in previous builds. Looks like I am updating today :)